# iPhone: I am having trouble with memory iteratively building up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am having trouble with memory building up and am not able to empty it once I am done with it.  When I look at the diagnostic tool ": Allocations: Instruments: Object summary: statistics", the memory is just continuously building up.

example:

```
for (int i=0; i<100000; i++){
    UILabel *lblPost = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,d)];
    [lblPost setText: "Hello World"];
    [self.view addSubview: lblPost];

    // tried each of the following
    //[lblPost dealloc]; //neither work to clear memory it just builds
    //[lblPost release]; //
}
```

--> Do I need to seperate CGRect out and clear that.

--> (I know I can just keep writing to one label, this is a simplified version where in the bigger version, one label would not work so easily. )

--> (I find it hard to believe that I can not create an object and then destroy it 10000 or 100000000 times over.  In standard C, I can accomplish this with memory-blocks by using "free()"  )

Comment: You should not call dealloc - release should do the trick. Could you give a bit more detail ?

Comment: Basically, how do you kill off an object once you are done with it.  Release, dealloc, [self.view release], [self release], none seem to work.  The idea here is create a label, kill it when done, and create another label... etc.

Comment: Calling release on lblPost is the correct thing to do after adding it to self.view. It is retained by self.view when you add it as a subview and will be released at the appropriate time in that views lifecycle (e.g. when it disappears). Memory is increasing because you are adding 10000 labels to the view.

Comment: jdl: the problem is, even after you release it the label won't be removed from memory until it is removed from its superview. And presumably, you put it in the superview because you needed it there. If you don't need 10000 labels displaying in the view, then don't add them as subviews in the first place.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that I can not create an object and then destroy it 10000 or 100000000 times over. In standard C, I can accomplish this with memory-blocks by using "free()"

Comment: @jdl. You can do that in Objective-C. Add `[lblPost removeFromSuperview]`, and that's what you'd have. But that's not what you're doing in the code above. If the object were destroyed at the end of the loop, the view would be left holding a pointer to a UILabel that no longer exists, and you'd crash. So the UILabel MUST continue to exist until the parent view removes it, which you're never doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fun!  I have decided to jump in.  I posted this in my comments but here it is again:

I think madhu misunderstood the [lblPost release]. This "release" only applies to the lblPost instance. Not the ones retained by self.view... etc. So you still have 10000 label retained by self.view...

So, you create 10000 instances of lblPost and then release all of them (10000) by this line [lblPost release] in your for loop.  That is just fine.  But then in your for loop you also have this line [self.view addSubview: lblPost].  This line will add 10000 instances to your self.view.  And they are the reason why your system crashed.

Comment: Thanks for jumping in.  Bottom line is I want to cycle creation and destruction of a text object to the screen.  I don't want it hanging around once each cycle is done.  My code was an example.  If there is a better way to cycle creation and destruction of an object please let me know... thank you

Comment: Try this, add this line before release the lblPost: [lblPost removeFromSuperview]

Comment: Here is what I have tried on my system:

    for (int i=0; i<10000; i++){
        UILabel *lblPost = [[UILabel alloc] nitWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,100,55,45)];
        [lblPost setText: @"Hello World"];
        [self.view addSubview: lblPost];
        
        // tried each of the following
        //[lblPost dealloc]; //neither work to clear memory it just builds
        [lblPost removeFromSuperview];
        [lblPost release];
}

And I use the Xcode 4's Instruments to monitor memory usage.  It is working fine.

Comment: It works... but the memory is still building up in the memory monitor.  Though not as much memory is building up as before.  So something else is building up as well.

Answer (score 3):

The view you are adding your label to is retaining it, that's why each none of the labels is deallocated (even if you send release message)

Comment: I did try: [self.view release];
 [self release]; and neither worked... actually it crashes out.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe i really don't understand what you're trying to do, but your each indiviual object you'r allocating is retained in the view. Let me try to explain it in the code:

```
 for (int i=0; i<10000; i++){
  UILabel *lblPost = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,d)];
 // lblPost now has a retain count of 1, as you alloc'd it, you'll have to release it!
  [lblPost setText: "Hello World"];
  [self.view addSubview: lblPost];
 // lblPost now has a retain count of 2, as adding to the view adds a reference to it
  [lblPost release]
 // you alloc'd it, now you should release it. it now has a retain count of 1, which means it's in the ownerhsip of the self.view
}
```

Now, when you release or free self.view, the lblPost objects should be released as well

Answer (score 1):

Why are you allocating memory for **10000** `UILabel`s and **adding them as a subview** exactly? That's iPhone torture. The items in bold cause your surge in memory. Plus you're **releasing none of them**.

Also - never ever ever call `dealloc` yourself - `dealloc` is called automatically when you `release` something.

[image]

Comment: this is an example cross section of something larger. I used dealloc after I tried to "release memory" and it didn't work.

Comment: superb word iphone torture for that i voting .as u said he would add 10000 label then he will ask about his crash.comedy!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I am not sure if you understand me correctly - `10000` UILabel = no no. You don't get this much RAM assigned. Plus putting them into a loop is bound to cause a crash. Reconsider this, it'll not work this way.

Comment: Thank you :P It really is iPhone torture, tried it myself and look what happened above! :P

Comment: For one thing this is an example of something larger.  If I release the memory after each time, it should not be a problem??

Comment: Or simply, how do I kill the memory space so it doesn't build up?

Comment: Yes it will be a problem. You're adding 10000 instances of UILabel in a loop, adding the view and keeping it in memory until it is removed from the stack takes up a lot of memory in this volume! 10000 is crazy.

Comment: You can't "kill it". Please read the documentation on view stacks. You can prevent this by not creating the same UILabel 10000 times.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think he was actually adding 10000 UILabels. It seems like he was trying to come up with a similar scenario to what he was experiencing.

Comment: I can only comment on the code I see. I don't have his project.

Comment: You need to make your code clearer `jdl`. My scenario is what the other answers are about too.

Comment: I think the question is clear and the code summaries the problem as you have seen for yourself.  If a person can not clear memory of object no longer needed, bottom line, any app that uses lots of objects will inherently get slow because you can't release them.  This is bull, because in standard-c I can create and destroy memory space at will a billion times over.

Comment: You obviously have no idea how the view stack system works. So please read up in the documentation before posting comments like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<10000; i++){
    UILabel *lblPost = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,d)];
    [lblPost setText: "Hello World"];
    [self.view addSubview: lblPost];

    [lblPost release];
    //You should release after adding it to your view


}
```

Comment: Like I said, I tried  "[lblPost release]".  The diagnostic tool shows that memory is still building up.  On the iPhone, it crashes after awhile.

Comment: That's because you're using too much memory! `10000 UILabel` take more memory than you can have in your sandbox environment. Read my answer.

Comment: But you're adding them as a subview, don't you think that takes no memory? It just turns into vapor as soon as you call `release`? Don't think so.

Comment: I think madhu misunderstood the [lblPost release].  This "release" only applies to the lblPost instance.  Not the one retain by self.view... etc.  So you still have 10000 label retained by self.view...

Comment: My typo on the lasts comment... it needed to be "Not the ones .."  This line [self.view addSubview: lblPost] was in the loop, so you are adding 10000 instances to the self.view....